# How to zoom google line chart in angular-google-charts?

Tags: angular, angular6, google-visualization

I am using angular-google-charts for plotting line chart in my application. I want to add a zoom-able functionality as data points are too many. How can I achieve the same?

I have passed below attributes in options

```
explorer: {
          actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
          axis: 'horizontal',
          keepInBounds: true,
          maxZoomIn: 4.0
     }
```

Comment: what type of values are on the x-axis? the `explorer` option is only supported by a [continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Terminology) axis (number, date, etc...) -- not a discrete axis (string)

Comment: I am having number on x axis

Comment: please share a sample of the data, a full example would be more helpful...